# Finding words from a string with regex findall function but has to be utf-8 encoding

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have to return all words from a string that start with a capital letter and are followed by at least one lower-case letter, but my problem is that I have to use UTF-8 encoding, but I don´t know how to add this into the code.

For example I have a string:

```
'KanaMunaPelmeen!!ApelsinÕunMandariinKakaoHernesAhven'
```

I should return:

```
['Kana', 'Muna', 'Pelmeen', 'Apelsin', 'Õun', 'Mandariin', 'Kakao', 'Hernes', 'Ahven']
```

My code so far is:

```
def find_words(text: str) -> list:
    pattern = r"[A-Z]+[a-z]*"
    match = re.findall(pattern, text)
    return match
```

So my result is:

```
['Kana', 'Muna', 'Pelmeen', 'Apelsin', 'Mandariin', 'Kakao', 'Hernes', 'Ahven']
```

How to write into the code to consider also UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: This has nothing to do with utf8, it simply that different languages have different definitions of what a "letter" is. Examples of letters from different languages:  `ü`, `ß`, `ж`, `ב` etc etc. Do you really want to match them all?

Comment: I need them to match certain language letters, so õ, ä, ö, ü must be included.

Comment: just include them in your pattern then, e.g. `'[A-ZÄÖÕÜ]+[a-zäöõü]*'`

Answer (score 1):

You can install [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and use

```py
import regex
text = 'KanaMunaPelmeen!!ApelsinÕunMandariinKakaoHernesAhven'
pattern = regex.compile(r'\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*')
print( pattern.findall(text) )
# => ['Kana', 'Muna', 'Pelmeen', 'Apelsin', 'Õun', 'Mandariin', 'Kakao', 'Hernes', 'Ahven']
```

See the [Python demo online](https://tio.run/##Nc6xCsIwEAbgPU@R4pBWpItzhW5CLbirQ9DTBtNLSFOpSB/DJ/LBYi/WJfkPcn8@@/SNwXUIqrXGee7gBgPzMHhecFFJlHWPcg@6BcAkKS3oTuHn3WMt8SKdUljJuzRbcAhd2TwABbPS@2meGmJdfjatVRpSJ472tetHOvW4FBmzTqFP@byQX9XUqXVK/2c8YwtebPghMsSKC6LQPXMoziCKhIqv/jAaIo7CDxhXIvIUwhc).

If you cannot install PyPi regex module you can use

```py
import re, sys
text = 'KanaMunaPelmeen!!ApelsinÕunMandariinKakaoHernesAhven'
pLu = '[{}]'.format("".join([chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if chr(i).isupper()]))
pLl = '[{}]'.format("".join([chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if chr(i).islower()]))
pattern = re.compile(fr'{pLu}{pLl}*')
print( pattern.findall(text) )
# => ['Kana', 'Muna', 'Pelmeen', 'Apelsin', 'Õun', 'Mandariin', 'Kakao', 'Hernes', 'Ahven']
```

See [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##rZAxbsMwDEV3n4JJB0lFoKVzCmQrkAbIbngQHLpmK1OCLKcJAh@jJ@rBXMlxe4Iu5Jfw@Qk@f42t46dpos67ECHgBvprX0S8RNiC2Bs2h4HNEW2HyKvVzqPtib@/Bj4YPplAxHvzYdwLBsZ@156RReFfhzxd3sZK6MaFzkS5Xut3RyzLug2SFKRvICCGYPgNZdqqO3MZmGp3QgXUwN2oqR@8xyBVpVRKtv@ZbN3nX7KJMd2Q0gPq2nWeLMomiFs6ZkzFjo8iuQJxlLCYdUOJgbUy81KgigfYPkM5YxMbEBld7gu@LBeAWWaIs@sXZH7MMLO4A51HZqjVNP0A).